# Receive Data from javascript

Tags: objective-c

i have a stupid question...sometimes i see developers use the following code...

```
NSString *newURL = [_parameters objectForKey:@"url"];
```

when i use this i get error... here what is _parameters and how to declare it??

i can provide more example..

```
        NSLog(@"SaveImage Called");
        //google code for turning base64 into uiimage
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self._parameters objectForKey:@"imageData"]];    
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];   
   /*
   if(img != nil) {
      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, nil, nil);
   }
   */
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript...

Comment: I retagged the question to `objective-c`. Feel free to revert it if you give a good reason why it should be tagged javascript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_parameters` is a [**NSDictionary**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary) that seems to be defined previously in the code, e.g.

```
NSDictionary _parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", nil
                                         forKeys:@"url", @"host", nil];
```

What exactly is your question? How is this related to JavaScript (edit: question was tagged as javascript)? You know that the language you use is *Objective-C* ?